# Delete task on case when case is cancelled

Tags: trigger

I have a trigger on case , which deletes the tasks when the case status is set to cancelled. The owd  for "Activity" is set to 'controlled by Parent' and the parent - "Case" is also set to Private. But, I have a sharing rule on case which gives Read/write access to the users with same role . So when I try to cancel a case which is having tasks created by another user with the same role . I get the below error message. [image]

Below is the code I wrote in trigger. and the error comes in line - delete tasksToDeletelist;

```
public static void onAfterUpdate(List<Case> newcaseslist, map<id, CAse> oldMAp){
    Set<Id> caseIdSet = new Set<Id>();

    List<Task> tasksToDeletelist = new list<Task>();
    for(Case c : newcaseslist )
    {
        Case oldCase =oldMap.get(c.id);
        if(c.status == 'Cancelled' && c.status != oldCase.status){
            caseIdSet.add(c.Id);
        }


    }  
    system.debug(caseIdSet);

    if(!caseIdSet.isEmpty()){
       for (Case cs: [Select Id, (Select Id, WhatId from tasks where Status != 'Completed') from Case where Id IN: caseIdSet AND RecordType.Name IN ('ABC','HPC')]) 

        //for(Case cs : [Select Id , (Select Id, WhatId from tasks where Status != 'Completed') from Case where Id IN : caseIdSet ])
        {
            if( cs.tasks != null && !cs.tasks.isEmpty())
            {
                    tasksToDeletelist.addAll(cs.tasks);                     
            }    
        }

        if(!tasksToDeletelist.isEmpty()){
            delete tasksToDeletelist;
        }
    }



}
```

How do I delete the tasks created by some other user. ? please suggest.

Comment: I am able to read and Edit the case record created by other profile with the same role . But why Am I not able to delete the task created by another user with different profile but same role. What actually is Controlled By Parent OWD doing ?

Answer (score 2):

Controller By Parent means owner of the Case will have full control on the tasks associated with the Case.

The other user on the same role will get Read-Write access to the Case, doesn't mean that he can delete the task which is owned by other user, unless user has Modify All permission at profile level.

To handle this use case, make trigger handler **without sharing** and it will work.

Otherwise, before deletion of the task, assigned the task to that user's name and finally delete.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Using without sharing breaks the existing rules . Is there any other way that I can do it ?

Comment: Otherwise, before deletion of the task, assigned the task to that user's name and finally delete.

Comment: @SantanuBoral - Unless the user has transfer permissions not sure they can assign it to themselves either. But I did not test it so....

Comment: I would still recommend to have separate class designated with "without sharing" only for deletion. otherwise you know under the hood how salesforce does complex reassignment

Answer (score 1):

Delete permissions always follow the role hierarchy, sharing rules can not confer delete access, or transfer (change owner) access.

Therefore the delete has to be done without sharing, or via an autolaunched flow (process builder, while built on the flow engine, does not offer a delete Action at present)

Autolaunched flows run in system mode (ie without sharing) and therefore could delete the task. The flow would be triggered by a process that fires when case status == cancelled, and then it would use a fast lookup to select the correct activities and a fast  delete element to delete them.

It would be a very straightforward 2-3 step flow.

Comment: Hi Gorav, Can you please elaborate on how this can be done using process.. Thanks.!

Comment: Hi Sandhya, sorry looks like process builder still doesn't have delete action, so you would need to use it to launch a flow. I provided an outline for what the flow would do, it would be straightforward, happy to assist if any questions arise.

Comment: Note that as of 2020 screen flows can now run in system mode, so you should be able to allow delete / transfer via a screen flow also.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Santanu with putting `without sharing`, but I wanted to refactor your code slightly, you're doing multiple things I don't believe you need to unless there are requirements I don't understand

I also believe you shouldn't be sending a `List<Case>` rather a `Set<ID>` which could be an `Account`, `Case`, `Lead` etc.. and you would be able to make this a more generic `deleteTasksByWhatID` method and then you'd move this method to a TaskTriggerHandler class.  This goes past your initial question, but it's my two cents ..

```
public static void onAfterUpdate(List<Case> casesList)
{
    Set<Id> caseIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    Set<String> recordTypesToEvaulate = new Set<String>{'InterConsultation','HP InterConsultation'};

    List<Task> tasksToDeletelist = new list<Task>();

    for(Case c : casesList)
    {
        if(c.Status == 'Cancelled' && recordTypesToEvaulate.contains(c.RecordType.Name))
        {
            caseIdSet.add(c.Id);
        }
    }  

    if(!caseIdSet.isEmpty())
    {
        for (Task t : [SELECT ID FROM Task WHERE WhatID =:caseIdSet WHERE Status != 'Completed']) 
        {
            tasksToDeletelist.addAll(t);                      
        }

       delete tasksToDeletelist;     
    }
}
```